# Vim: Delete all blank lines until first non-blank line

Tags: vim

I have some text like this:

```
Line 1 of text





Line 2 of text.
```

I want to delete all the blank lines between the two lines of text.

I could put my cursor under the first line and type `5dd`, but I'm wondering if it can be done without specifying a number of lines.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Starting from the first blank line from Normal mode, press `d/.`. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

`d` will delete until `/` finds the first non-blank character (anything matching `.`).

Comment: And if you want to include lines with white-space: `d/^\s*$`

Comment: I would out of habit have used `g/^$/d` but this just feels better.

Answer (score 0):

While in Normal mode, place you cursor on any line of blank text between the two non-blank lines, then type `dip` for **d**elete **i**nner **p**aragraph.

This will delete all empty lines between two blocks of text.